# jQuery ajax 'toLowerCase' error with a basic POST method but works for similar DELETE method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a basic post and I get a 'toLowerCase' error.

My URL is "developer/58ace2b191e01c24f61fc241/broke"
and the request is "http://localhost:8080/developer/58ace2b191e01c24f61fc241/broke", but for some reason this doesn't work.

```
broke = function (url) {
var request = getRootUrl() + url;
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});
$.post(request, function(data) {
    console.log("hit");
});
};
```

However, I have this very similar delete method that does work:

```
makeDeleteCall = function (url) {
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: getRootUrl() + url
});
};
```

Full stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at Object.setRequestHeader (http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.js:4:19436)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/developer.js:22:13)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.js:3:8436)
at HTMLDocument.m.event.add.r.handle (http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.js:3:5139)
at Object.trigger (http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.js:3:7537)
at Function.ajax (http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.js:4:21187)
at Function.m.each.m.(anonymous function) [as post] (http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.js:4:22297)
at broke (http://localhost:8080/js/developer.js:24:7)
at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick (http://localhost:8080/newDev:58:136)
```

So, why does this work for one ajax call (DELETE) but not another (POST)?

Comment: where in the code have you used `toLowerCase` ?

Comment: have you tried same method as with DELETE. I mean using $.ajax instead of $.post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csrf tokens were not set on the page with the POST like so:

```
    <meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

But on the page where the DELETE button worked they were set. Since they were undefined it was causing jQuery to blow up.